# npm global install on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am running into an issue installing pm2 globally on aws elastic beanstalk. I created the following script for installing pm2:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production
container_commands:
  01_enable_rootaccess:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers 
  02_install_imagemagic:
    command: yum install -y ImageMagick
  03_download_new_relic:
    command: rpm -Uvh http://download.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/i386/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm 
    ignoreErrors: true
  04_install_new_relic:
    command: yum install -y newrelic-sysmond
    ignoreErrors: true
  05_add_license_key:
    command: /usr/sbin/nrsysmond-config --set license_key=xxxxxxx
    ignoreErrors: true
  06_start_new_relic:
    command: /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond start
    ignoreErrors: true
  07_install_pm2:
    command: sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/npm install pm2 -g
    ignoreErrors: true    
  08_stop_old_pm2_processes:
    command: sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/pm2 delete all
    ignoreErrors: true
  09_start_pm2:
    command: sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/pm2 startup -u ec2-user
    ignoreErrors: true
```

I have tried using just 'pm2 delete all' and 'pm2 startup' for commands 8 & 9 put i just get command not found. when i give the specific path to pm2(i logged on to the ec2 and verified) i get "line 4: exec: : not found". any idea what i am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I managed to install pm2 globally on elastic beanstalk with the following code snippet embedded in an .ebextensions/your_file_name.config file

```
container_commands:
  01_node_symlink:
    command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/node /bin/node"
  02_npm_symlink:
    command: "ln -sf `ls -td /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-* | head -1`/bin/npm /bin/npm"
  03_pm2_install:
    command: "if [ ! -e /bin/pm2 ]; then npm install pm2 -g; fi"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to ensure that the `nodejs-legacy` module is installed.  If `pm2` is depending on the executable named `node`, that will fail when the system installs it globally as `nodejs` as some Linux systems (Ubuntu, Debian) often do.